# Change Gitlab CI Runner user

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently when I start a build in GitlabCI it is running under gitlab-runner user. I want to change it the company's internal user. I didn't find any parameter to the /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml which is solve that.

My current configuration:

```
concurrent = 1
[[runners]]
  name = "deploy"
  url = ""
  token = ""
  executor = "shell"
```

Comment: The gitlab-runner run command takes a ----user option allowing to specify the user.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Running `ps aux | grep gitlab` you can see:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-ci-multi-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
```

Service is running with option `--user`.

So let's change this, it depends on what distro. you are running it. If systemd, there is a file:

/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service:

```
[Service]
StartLimitInterval=5
StartLimitBurst=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gitlab-ci-multi-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/home/gitlab-runner" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--se
```

Bingo, let's change this file now:

```
gitlab-runner uninstall

gitlab-runner install --working-directory /home/ubuntu --user ubuntu
```

reboot the machine or reload the service (i.e. `systemctl daemon-reload`), et voilà!

Comment: I think these kind of cli is new, because I looked for something similar, but the cli didn't support it yet. Thank you and nice answer.

Comment: Yeah GitlabCI is moving very fast, they add new features but sometimes new bugs, so always upgrade with caution!

Comment: This returns - `FATAL: flag provided but not defined: -user`

Comment: @letsc try `--user`

Comment: @letsc It will not report this '-user' error when `sudo gitlab-runner install`

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 I used `service gitlab-runner restart` to reload the service

Comment: After changed user "Error: Job Failed: prepare environment: exit status 1...."

Answer (score 16):

Note that when installing with a specific user (--user), whenever you update, it will revert back to the original systemd script and so, back to using gitlab-runner user.

in order to keep the user change across updates, using systemd overrides (centos7) you can use these steps (assuming service is at `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service`):

1. Create a `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service.d` directory.
2. Create a `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service.d/exec_start.conf` file, with content:

   ```
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner "run" "--working-directory" "/home/ubuntu" "--config" "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" "--service" "gitlab-runner" "--syslog" "--user" "ubuntu"
   ```
3. Execute `systemctl daemon-reload`

Now to check this is working, you can do this:

1. Reinstall GitLab Runner package `gitlab-runner uninstall` and then `gitlab-runner install`
2. Check `ps aux | grep gitlab` and confirm the right user is being used

source: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3675

Comment: Upvote! Thank you for adding the helpful bit about making it persistent.

Comment: I had to do `systemctl restart gitlab-runner` as well in order the system service command to be launched with the new user.

Answer (score 13):

Once the `gitlab-runner` is registered (yes, it will be installed under the user `gitlab-runner` and working directory `/home/gitlab-runner` ) you can execute the following to change the runner's user

```
gitlab-runner uninstall
```

```
gitlab-runner install --working-directory <existing-path> --user <any-existing-user>

# eg: gitlab-runner install --working-directory /home/ec2-user --user ec2-user
```

then restart the service

```
service gitlab-runner restart
```

> NOTE: you don't need to edit `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service` for this, as it is being updated once the service is restarted as above

to check if the configurations are reflecting, run

```
ps aux | grep gitlab
```

Answer (score 2):

[DEPRECATED ANSWER]

I found a solution, which is not best pactrice but solved it. I need to use the ssh executer and ssh to localhost. It is require to add gitlab-runner id_rsa.pub to the user's authorized_keys what you want to use. There is my extended code:

```
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "deploy"
  url = ""
  token = ""
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "user"
    host = "localhost"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Comment: Why do you consider this not "best practice"? Unless you're prepared to use a VM or container solution, this looks like your only option.

Comment: @Auspex this is nearly 5 years old, Gitlab changed a lot since then.

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't see another way to run commands as a different user. I'm not prepared to implement docker runners for a single repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, I was doing a test with a cloned version of my setup, if the domainname is not pointing to the server you are working with, gitlab might consider your runners offline. If you have another (copied) instance running at the ip the domain is pointing at and there is no firewall blocking, the gitlab-runner verify command will say your runners are alive.

a solution could be adding your domain pointing to 127.0.0.1 to your hosts file. you'll have to restart your gitlab instance and runners.

Answer (score 0):

For recent version of gitlab-runner you should modify the system arguments in the `/etc/default/gitlab-runner` file.

Answer (score 0):

Here example for **docker** gitlab-runner:

Build your own runner image based on Dockerfile with following content

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner
# add new user (if needed)
RUN useradd -u 998 gitlab-www && mkdir /home/gitlab-www && \
    chown gitlab-www /home/gitlab-www && chmod u+rwx /home/gitlab-www
# need to replace entrypoint to force new created user over gitlab-runner
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/dumb-init /entrypoint run --user=gitlab-www --working-directory=/home/gitlab-www
```

(update `-u 998` and `gitlab-www` as you need)

.gitlab-ci.yml scripts are running as user `gitlab-www` now. If this one has same uid as host mounts, you are also able to deploy directly to host folders.

Comment: The `useradd` in `gitlab/gitlab-runner` doesn't have `--create-home`? I'd have thought : `RUN useradd --create-home -u 998 gitlab-www`