# Is ti possible to change the default user for the build process to a custom user?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

gitlab-ci-multi-runner uses gitlab-runner as the user when using the shell executor. Is ti possible to change the default user for the build process to a custom user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Gitlab CI Runner user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187899/change-gitlab-ci-runner-user)