# Global environment variables for gitlab CI runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working to set up a gitlab runner for multiple projects, and we want to be able to set up environment variables for all of the projects.  I tried to set global variables in the `.bashrc` for both the `gitlab-runner` and `root` users but it did not recognize them during the CI script.  What is the correct location to declare global environment variables?

Comment: Same issue: Runners run on different machines, which are slightly different. (Let's say some path) I want to use different environment variables for each runners.

Answer (score 3):

You can also inject environment variables to your gitlab-runner directly in the commandline, as the `gitlab-runner exec docker --help` states:

> OPTIONS: ..
> --env value                                           Custom environment variables injected to build environment [$RUNNER_ENV] ..

Here is a small example how I use it in a script:

Change the declarations as needed:

```
declare jobname="your_jobname"
declare runnerdir="/path/to/your/repository"
```

Get the env file into a bash array.

```
[ -f "$runnerdir/env" ] \
&& declare -a envlines=($(cat "$runnerdir/env"))
declare -a envs=()
for env in "${envlines[@]}"; do
  envs+=(--env "$env")
done
```

And finally pass it to the gitlab-runner.

```
[ -d "$runnerdir" ] && cd "$runnerdir" \
&& gitlab-runner exec docker "${envs[@]}" $jobname \
&& cd -
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define environment variables to inject in the runner's `config.toml` file. See the [advanced runner configuration documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) in the `[[runners]]` section.

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify environment variables in the GitLab UI just for a specific runner.

Answer (score 1):

With [GitLab 13.1 (June 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/06/22/gitlab-13-1-released/#instance-level-cicd-variables), you now have:

> ### Instance-level CI/CD variables
>
> GitLab now supports instance-level variables.
> **With this ability to set global variables, you no longer need to manually enter the same credentials repeatedly for all your projects**.
>
> This MVC introduces access to this feature by API, and the next iteration of this feature will provide the ability to configure instance-level variables directly in the UI.

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/instance_level_ci_variables.html) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14108).

Answer (score 1):

Making changes in `~/.bash_profile` **NOT** `~/.bashrc`.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69126217/1294349)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an external persistent secret storage service like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) or [Keywhiz](https://square.github.io/keywhiz/)

Disclaimer: I am not associated nor used any of the above services

Answer (score 0):

I have added `export MY_VAR="FOO"` to `gitlab-runner`'s `.bashrc`, and it works.

```
echo export MY_VAR=\"FOO\" >> /home/gitlab-runner/.bashrc
```

Check which type of executor do you use? (shell, kubernetes, docker-ssh, parallels...) I use shell executor.

Check what type of shell does `gitlab-runner` use? ([How to determine the current shell I'm working on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3327022/2506522)) And edit the [proper `rc` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3052/131168) for that.

Check the [Gitlab CI Runner user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37187899/2506522).

---

I suggest dump all environment variables for further debugging, by add `env` to the `.gitlab-ci.yml`'s script:

```
#.gitlab-ci.yml

job:
  script: env
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily setup Variables in the GitLab Settings:

> Project-level variables can be added by going to your project's Settings > CI/CD, then finding the section called Variables.

To make sure your variables are only used in

See:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables