# Gitlab CI/CD runner : mvn command not found

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Maven** is well installed on my **gitlab-runner** server. When executing `mvn clean` directly on my repo it works, when running my pipeline using Gitlab UI got this error :

> bash: line 60: mvn: command not found
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

I notice that I tried to fix the problem by adding the `before_script` section in the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file :

```
before_script:    
- export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven
```

I add also the line :

```
environment = ["MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven"]
```

on the  **config.toml** file.

the problem still persist, my executor is : **shell**.

Any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem using this workaround:

```
  script:
    - $MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn clean
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add the maven docker image, add below line as first line:

```
image: maven:latest or image: maven:3-jdk-10 or image: maven:3-jdk-9
```

refer: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way:
Making changes in `~/.bash_profile` not `~/.bashrc`.

---

According to [this document](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html#sect_03_01_02):

> `.bashrc` it is more common to use a non-login shell

[This document](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/#shbash-shells) saying:

> For certain executors, the runner passes the `--login` flag as shown above, which also loads the shell profile.

So it should not be `~/.bashrc`, you can also try `~/.profile` which  `It can hold the same configurations, which are then also accessible by other shells`

---

In my scenario I do following things:

#### 1. Set `gitlab-runner`'s user password.

`passwd gitlab-runner`

#### 2. Login `gitlab-runner`.

`su - gitlab-runner`

#### 3. Make changes in `.bash_profile`

Comment: This works for my use case. Just adding $HOME/.local/bin to the path and it wasn't working in .bashrc. Switched to .bash_profile and it works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Add maven to PATH:

```
$ export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9

$ export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

$ export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

You can include these commands in `$HOME/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you had figure out your question. I met the same question when I build my ci on my server.

I use the shell as the executer for my Runner. 
here are the steps to figure out.

### 1 check the user on the runner server

if you had install maven on the runner server successfully, maybe it just successful for the root, u can check the real user for the ci process.

```sh
job1:
  stage: test
  script:  whoami
```

if my case, it print `gitlab-runner`, not the `root`

### 2 su the real user, check mvn again

In this time, it print error as same as the Gitlab ci UI.

### 3 install maven for the real user. run the pipeline again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing similar issues, it might be a good idea to restart the gitlab runner ".\gitlab-runner.exe restart". Especially after fiddling with environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as per below in the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
  - export PATH=$PATH:/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin
```