# Commands in git-lab-runner on windows machine not working

Tags: cmd, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-runner installed on my windows 10.
When I try to use commands like pip and sh in my .gitlab-ci.yml file the runner does not recognize these commands even though they are recognized in my windows machine when run using cmd.
All the environment variables have been setup properly on my windows machine.

i.e pip works on my windows machine but not on my gitlab-runner.
[Refer this link](https://gitlab.com/gkp1998/pythonfile/-/jobs/249357469)

My config.toml file has been set to "cmd".

> Error seen: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting

> before_script:
>   - SET SH_HOME=C:\cygwin64

resolved the issue referring  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535771/gitlab-ci-cd-runner-mvn-command-not-found?rq=1)