# Running local GitLab CI with shell executor and flag --user $USER for gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to set up a CI environment on a local GitLab install.
I am testing basic shell commands that need to be run within the regular user (the value of `$USER`) environment.
By default the gitlab-runner service is configured with `--user gitlab-runner`.
So first I followed the answer provided at [Change Gitlab CI Runner user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187899/change-gitlab-ci-runner-user) to assign another user.
This seemed to work as the output of `ps aux | grep runner` is as expected and I hit the `clear_console` error from `.bash_logout` described at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4559.
After commenting out the content of `.bash_logout` I now get the following error.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.3.2 (e0218c92)
...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
error: could not lock config file /home/gitlab-runner/builds/y762gpjf/0/root/test.tmp/git-template/config: Permission denied
```

This happens before any command from `.gitlab-ci.yml` gets interpreted so I am stuck here.
Also it seems that gitlab-runner is definitely not designed to be run with the regular user account. Is that a fair assumption?

#### EDIT: solution implemented based on the answers

Indeed, the new user did not have access to the working directory of the runner.
So before installing the runner I ran

```
sudo usermod -aG gitlab-runner $USER
sudo chmod g+wx /home/gitlab-runner/
```

and then

```
sudo gitlab-runner install --user=$USER --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
```

Comment: If you have changed the gitlab-runner user, the path of the jobs should not start by `/home/gitlab-runner` which is the homedir of the default user. I think the new user has no right to write in `/home/gitlab-runner` because it has a different uid/gid than the default gitlab-runner user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Davide mentioned in the comments, when you update the user for gitlab-runner, you also need to update its working directory to ensure that it has permissions to that directory. Alternatively, you could grant the new user access to `/home/gitlab-runner`, it's your choice. To install the gitlab-runner with a different user and working directory, the command is: `gitlab-runner install --user=my_user --working-directory=/home/my_user` ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html#install-1))