# rootless podman can not run some commands

Tags: centos8, podman

I had a problem with gitlab running podman commands with gitlab-runner user and I could not see the created containers with my user. I chaned the user as described in [Change Gitlab CI Runner user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187899/change-gitlab-ci-runner-user).
I ran the gitlab pipeline again and it went successfully through 3 steps and created a podman pod and 2 other containers in it. Suddenly it stoped by a podman run for the last container. I checked the server and gave `podman ps -a` but nothing happend after pressing enter and I could still write in command line!
I wrote `podman images list` and I could see the images list (2 images have the same id and I can not remove them!!).
I tried `sudo podman ps` and it worked!
Some commands just work and some commands are not working as rootless. my user can not do `podman run`  from Gitlab but on the server my user can run `podman run hello-world`!
I get no error just it remains in that state and I have to cancle the job.

I am using centos 8, podman 3.3.1.
sudo podman info:

```
host:

arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.22.3
  cgroupControllers:
  - cpuset
  - cpu
  - cpuacct
  - blkio
  - memory
  - devices
  - freezer
  - net_cls
  - perf_event
  - net_prio
  - hugetlb
  - pids
  - rdma
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.29-1.module+el8.5.0+12582+56d94c81.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.29, commit: 0f5bee61b18d4581668e5bf18b910cda3cff5081'
  cpus: 40
  distribution:
    distribution: '"rhel"'
    version: "8.5"
  eventLogger: file
  hostname: DELL2
  idMappings:
    gidmap: null
    uidmap: null
  kernel: 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  memFree: 55734177792
  memTotal: 134510010368
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.0.2-1.module+el8.5.0+12582+56d94c81.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version 1.0.2
      spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.16.7
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: false
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.module+el8.5.0+12582+56d94c81.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.8
      commit: d361001f495417b880f20329121e3aa431a8f90f
      libslirp: 4.4.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  swapFree: 4294963200
  swapTotal: 4294963200
  uptime: 11h 30m 52.88s (Approximately 0.46 days)
registries:
  search:
  - registry.fedoraproject.org
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.centos.org
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /etc/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mountopt: nodev,metacopy=on
  graphRoot: /var/lib/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "true"
  imageStore:
    number: 2
  runRoot: /run/containers/storage
  volumePath: /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.3.1
  Built: 1632213702
  BuiltTime: Tue Sep 21 10:41:42 2021
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.16.7
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 3.3.1
```

Command line keeps listening and nothing comes back.
[image: I can keep writing!!:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was SELinux problem. I turned it off and restarted the server. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem reproducible? Why I am asking because I think it should not be the case with podman but a specific issue at your end.

Comment: It happens since last update and restarting the server. It is not reproducible I guess. It is the state by me now

Comment: update: leaving the podman command like podman ps for almost 10 min led to shell time out. but running as sudo podman ps works

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem agian today. I ran systemctl --user restart podman.service and it fixed the problem this time.